# Scripts at the end of the page

Tags: plugins, javascript, scripts

If I wanted to put the scripts that all my plugins use at the end of the page, where would I do this?
Using YSlow/Firebug it recommends this tactic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hook for registering the script in the footer is:

```
<?php
function my_init_method() {
    wp_register_script( 'myscript', 'http://www.mydomain.com/js/myscript.js','','','true');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}    

add_action('init', 'my_init_method');
?>
```

be sure to look at [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script) and [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script), both are important.

Comment: Probably enqueue `myscript` and not `jquery`. Also I'd pass `array(), null` rather than `'', ''` in parameters there. It doesn't expect string for first and `null` for second will suppress version tag (relatively recent improvement).

Comment: yes. I should had thought about it.

Comment: I've tested this with one plugin so far. Looks good, thanks. Will try and get them all done at some point!

Answer (score 1):

One way - make use of queue. [`wp_register_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script) accepts parameter that bumps queued scripts to footer. The issue is that not all plugins use queue (they really should) and many that do don't bother to target footer. So you will need to hook and do a lot of registrations and re-registrations.

Another way is using good caching plugin (like [W3 Total Cache](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/w3-total-cache/)) that is capable of moving and even concatenating scripts.